# How do I change the Site Feed item limit?

Tags: social, sitefeed

My organization has a site feed web part on the home page of our intranet site where user's can post what's going on throughout the company. The current SharePoint default for the site feed is to display 20 items. I have not been able to find a way to modify this default setting. Any Ideas?

This is for the "SITE FEED / Microblogging" web part

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? We are facing the same problem as the default limit of Site Feed items is a bit too much for our liking. :)